# Gitflow error can't initialize

Tags: git

I've got gitflow installed in my directory where my github project is.
However, when I try to start with the command "`git flow init`", I get the following error messages:

```
git flow init
C:/cygwin64/usr/local/bin/gitflow-shFlags: line 1: shFlags/src/shflags: No such file or directory
C:\cygwin64\usr\local\bin\git-flow: line 85: DEFINE_boolean: command not found
C:\cygwin64\usr\local\bin\git-flow: line 88: FLAGS: command not found
fatal: 'flow' appears to be a git command, but we were not
able to execute it. Maybe git-flow is broken?
```

Any ideas of what I should do to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [issue 190](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow/issues/190) reports a similar problem, and suggests to restore the `shFlags/src/shflags` file yourself, using [`src/shflags`](https://github.com/nvie/shFlags/blob/master/src/shflags).

That file needs to be restored in order for the [git-flow call](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow/blob/15aab26490facf285acef56cb5d61025eacb3a69/git-flow#L80-L81) to [`gitflow-shFlags`](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow/blob/15aab26490facf285acef56cb5d61025eacb3a69/gitflow-shFlags) to succeed:

```
. "$GITFLOW_DIR/gitflow-shFlags"
```

With `gitflow-shFlags`:

```
shFlags/src/shflags
```

Comment: Make it so that file /usr/local/bin/gitflow-shFlags does not contain a single line buth rather the full file from the git repo (https://github.com/nvie/shFlags/blob/master/src/shflags).

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem like this! I've solved changing line 83 of git-flow file:

`#use the shFlags project to parse the command line arguments   . "$GITFLOW_DIR/gitflow-shFlags"`

to the value of `gitflow-shFlags`

`# use the shFlags project to parse the command line arguments
    . "$GITFLOW_DIR/shFlags/src/shflags"`