# git flow command results in - "Maybe git-flow is broken?"

Tags: git, git-flow

This git flow instructions video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rX80eKPdA28&t=302s involves giving the command: "*git flow release finish 0.2.0*" which opens up the vi editor.
I messed up the commit message and ended up closing the command prompt.

After this the command "git flow" results in an error message saying: Maybe git-flow is broken?
I have tried uninstalling git and reinstalled to no avail. Any ideas ?

Using Windows 10 and Developer Command Prompt VS 2022

**UPDATE**
I discovered that the issue was not related to **git-flow** but rather the ability to run a shell script such as **submodule** which didn't work either.
I haven't discovered the perfect solution but this is what I did.
My Windows account is not a local admin on my machine. I have another "admin" account. Previously I installed git using this admin account under c:\Program Files\Git.
Installing Git under my user account at c:\Users[myuser]\Document\Git fixed the issue.
I hope this helps someone.

Comment: Related, or possible dup: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27722909/184546

Comment: @TTT No. The other post relates to a different version than the current one unfortunately. This issue is different from the one I'm facing.

Comment: If you have a solution, do not add it as part of the _question_, add it as an _answer._

Comment: @matt I believe that my update does not really qualify as an answer, more of a workaround. The original issue still remains i.e. why did the git flow (or git submodule) commands stop working. There must be a reason for that.

Answer (score 1):

Git allows you to add custom commands. If you have a program installed titled `git-mything`, it can be invoked by running `git mything` because git will look up commands of that format when it doesn't recognize one.

So when you attempt to run `git flow`, git looks for a program called `git-flow` on your path. Presumably, you don't have one installed, so it can't find it.

This link here describes how to install git-flow: https://danielkummer.github.io/git-flow-cheatsheet/

That being said, "Gitflow" is just a style of working with git. I recommend reading https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows

Comment: Thanks for the help. git flow is installed by default since 2014 or 2015 I believe. It worked fine until I messed up the commit message.
I have the git-flow file located in the /git/usr/bin folder. I have another machine with the same path config. /git/usr/bin is actually not in path on either machine, yet it works.
I must have corrupted some file/setting/config which was not reset by my reinstall of git. 
Is there any setting in git which is stored somewhere else than in the Program Files/git folder ?